# Dynamic Data with Google Tag Manager and TurboLinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-tag-manager, turbolinks

How can I set up GTM with TurboLinks?

The problem:

GTM and the SEO team asks me to add this to my Head:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  dataLayer = [{'userID': '<%= current_user.id %>'},{'userCategory': 'User'}];
<% end %>
</script>
<!-- Paste this code as high in the <head> of the page as possible: -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-N7MDCP');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

This will be cached by TurboLinks.  I could try to wrap this in page:change, but that won't update the values for user_signed_in etc.

Can I safely move this into the body, where TurboLinks will refresh it? If not, how else can i get GTM to work with a dynmic datalayer and GTM?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Turbolinks docs, you have to add

`document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {`

to the beginning of a script that you don't want to be cached ([Turbolinks documentation reference)](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads).

See here for a [full example](https://makemore.coffee/2017/01/02/google-tag-manager-and-turbolinks-in-ruby-on-rails/).

Do the same for the dataLayer push script and include a console.log() in both scripts to make sure they're firing when they're supposed to and only when they're supposed to.

Comment: This isn't working at all for me.  The GTM events never fire. Have you tried testing this with the GTM preview / debug on? Do tag events show up in the footer?

Comment: also, i'd need the dataLayer push script to be run in ERB to get the correct values.  not just fired again by js with the first page view values, so that they are correct after login.

Comment: Yes, when I run it with GTM debug mode, the debug window only loads on the first load of a page or a refresh of a subsequent page, which is pretty annoying. However, if I refresh a page (to get debug mode to re-appear), any events or dataLayer pushes show up in the debugger. 

The reason I added `console.log("gtm fired");` is to see in the console when GTM was firing, regardless of what the debugger was doing.

For the erb code -- have you tried putting the `<script>` and `</script>` tags inside the erb code?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I safely move this into the body, where TurboLinks will refresh
>   it?

With a slight modification, yes.

Initialize the (empty) dataLayer variable above the GTM code.

```
var dataLayer = [];
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-N7MDCP');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager --
```

Any change in the dataLayer can be then added via the `push`-method (which is not the standard javascript array push, Google has overwritten that for the dataLayer with their own implementation). If you add a new value without a native event (load, DOM ready, window loaded) you need also to add a custom GTM event (`event` is a sort of reserved word in GTM; if you add an object with the key "GTM" to the dataLayer array GTM updates its internal data model with the new variables and you can use the event to fire tags).

So your implementation might look something like this (this goes in the body. Also while I know GTM I do not actually know Turbolinks, but you get the idea):

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
dataLayer.push({
'userID': '<%= current_user.id %>',
'userCategory': 'User',
'event':'loginStateChanged'
});
<% end %>
```

Now you can create a trigger within GTM of the type "custom event" with the event name of "loginStateChanged", and all tags that are fired with/after that trigger will have access to the userID and userCategory variables.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  If i try that for the header part of GTM, do I need to change the main body part? Testing the site with preview does not show an event unless the page is refreshed. Is GTM relying on page_load?

Comment: I've asked a secondary question which might make this clearer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449839/google-tag-manager-preview-does-not-display-when-navigating-to-pages-with-turbol